# Determine 'active' records

Tags: sql-server

I have a list of customers that can have a single, or multiple, service listed. In the table that houses the changes over time there is an indicator of 'Added' or 'Removed'.
What I need: determine those service(s) that are currently active, if at all.
Here is a sample set of data:

```
CUST_ID SRV_ID  STATUS  ACTION_DATE
12345   102 Added   1/31/17 10:15
12345   189 Added   4/18/17 15:37
12345   189 Removed 4/21/17 14:08
12345   194 Added   5/2/17 14:43
12345   194 Removed 5/5/17 10:02
12345   194 Added   5/5/17 13:06
12345   69  Added   4/19/17 9:36
12345   69  Removed 5/2/17 14:43
12345   73  Added   4/20/17 10:21
12345   73  Removed 4/25/17 11:20
12345   95  Added   5/4/17 9:48
12345   95  Removed 5/4/17 10:05
```

Records to be returned: 102 on 1/31/17 10:15 and 194 on 5/5/17 13:06

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the latest row for each cust_id and serv_id using `top 1 with ties` and window function `row_number` and then filter those with status "Added":

```
select *
from (
    select top 1
    with ties *
    from your_table
    order by row_number() over (
            partition by cust_id, srv_id
            order by action_date desc
            )
    ) t
where status = 'Added'
```

Produces:

```
CUST_ID SRV_ID  STATUS  ACTION_DATE
12345   102     Added   2017/01/31 10:15
12345   194     Added   2017/05/05 13:06
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/MEX68546)

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
SELECT SRV_ID
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY SRV_ID
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN STATUS='Added' THEN ACTION_DATE END)
     > MAX(CASE WHEN STATUS='Removed' THEN ACTION_DATE END)
```

Comment: Thank you, this only pulls the most recent record for the entire table.